# Rain during Hot Weather

Tags: rain, thunderstorm

During hot weather, it is uncommon for there to be rain without lightning and thunder if the weather is hot. I find that the general rule of thumb is that if it is raining while it is 70 degrees or higher, it is usually accompanied with lightning and thunder but still sometimes can happen at colder temperatures too like during the spring. However is it possible for there to be 85 to 90 degrees F without any lightning and thunder?

Comment: Duplicate ? https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18650/conditions-of-thunderstorms

Comment: It is not the same question so not it is not a duplicate. The answer also doesn’t make much sense to me

Comment: Thunderstorms don't form in hot weather alone, they can form when there's a temperature gradient with height and enough moisture for condensation. Frequently, hot weather is correlated with stable airmass, meaning no rain at all. You could read up on "convectional weather" and how thunderstorms form.

Comment: To answer: Yes it can be 29-32 C (or 85-90 F) without any lightning and thunder. But a better answer is that of @a_donda. You should probably read up on some basics.